# NodeJS синхронный get

Tags: javascript, node.js

Нужно установить `getter` для поля. `Getter` должен делать запрос к базе данных. У мне нужно, чтобы `getter` возвращал не `promise`, а значение

`console.log((new User(...)).proxy)`

```
async function fetchProxy() {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        database.query("SELECT `url` FROM `proxys` WHERE `in_use` = 0 LIMIT 1", function (err, result) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)).url);
        })
    });
}
```

В классе:

```
Object.defineProperties(this, {
    proxy: {
        _proxy: null,
        get: function () {
            if (!this._proxy) {
                this._proxy await fetchProxy();
            }
            return this._proxy;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ну вообще `getter` не может быть асинхронным https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790744/how-would-one-do-async-javascript-getters-and-setters

Comment: через Object.defineProperty работает, в Вашей же ссылки в ответе это написано

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько видимо не правильно выразился, имеется ввиду что `async/await` не применим к `getter`, только промис и возвращать

Comment: По определению невозможно синхронно получить результат асинхронной функции. Так что промизы или коллбеки

Answer (score -1):

async возвращает промис, Вы пытаетесь получить результат через

```
(new User(...)).proxy
```

но это промис в состоянии pending, чтобы получить значение Вам надо:

```
new User(...).proxy.then(result => console.log(result))
```

вот рабочий пример:

```js
const obj = {}

// как объявлять
Object.defineProperties(obj, {
  property: {
    async get () { // пример асинхронного гетера
      const result = await promise()
      
      return result
    }
  }
});

// как получить
obj.property.then(val => alert(val))


// промис для примера
function promise () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1200, 'Результат')
  })
}
```

UPDATE: 
**ThisMan**:

> зачем писать await? если в result промис, а не значение

Если у вас в геттере один промис, то его можно просто вернуть, чтобы он выполнился в `obj.property.then`:

```js
const obj = {}

// как объявлять
Object.defineProperties(obj, {
  property: {
    get: () => promise() 
  }
});

// как получить
obj.property.then(val => alert(val))


// промис для примера
function promise () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1200, 'Результат')
  })
}
```

Comment: зачем писать `await`, если в `result` промис, а не значение

Comment: вы не поняли вопроса автора, он хочет использовать `await` в геттере, этого нельзя делать, в любом случае промис будет возвращаться. Поэтому `async/await` в геттер не возможен

Comment: А из промиса никак не сделать сразу значение, надо писать `User(...).proxy.then` или `await User(...).proxy`. Я показал как сделать с then. `Поэтому async/await в геттер не возможен` что значит не возможен не пойму?

Comment: внутри геттера `await` не работает, следовательно и `async getter` не может тогда быть, потому что нет ожидания выполнения промиса

Comment: мы ожидаем уже где-то с наружи

Comment: плохо понимаю, буду благодарен за разъяснение. Почему await не работает внутри геттера? В моем первом коде `async get () {` работает, если использовать без defineProperties, например,  `async get latest()` то не будет работать.

Comment: если бы `await` работал, то геттер бы возвращал значение, а не промис

Comment: то есть гетер работал бы если `return result` возвращал бы значение, а не промис?

Comment: да, так как `await` как раз и делает, что возвращает результат промиса, а не сам промис

Comment: Я в чате, а Вы?